# Kill every python process name with psutil except one

Tags: python, kill, psutil

I'm using the following python script to kill every process with the given name:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "processname":
        proc.kill()
```

I want the script to leave one process with the given name open. How can I achieve this? Is it possibile using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply skip the first one:

```
piter = psutil.process_iter()
first = True
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "processname":
        if First:
            First = False
        else:
            proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working solution:

```
[func() for func in [proc.kill for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name()=="processname"][1:]]
```